# How to submit jquery ajax post request only once?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am checking out the final order in WordPress using jquery ajax post request.

My Add To Cart and Check out order has the same code but the checkout order code submits the request 3 times.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j('.wc-checkout').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var billing_customer_type = j("#billing_customer_type").val();
    // .. and so on...

    j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/mywebsite/?wc-ajax=checkout',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'billing_customer_type': billing_customer_type,
            // and so on..
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('Order Checked Out');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function() {}
    });
});


<form class="wc-checkout" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Lorem Ipsum: <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
        <select name="billing_customer_type" id="billing_customer_type"
            class="select thwcfd-enhanced-select select2-hidden-accessible enhanced"
            data-placeholder="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
        <!-- _wpnonce help protect URLs and forms from certain types of misuse -->
        '.wp_nonce_field("ajax_checkout").'
        <input type="submit" value="Order Now" class="epo-proceed-checkout-btn">
    </div>

</form>
```

Do you know how can i make the .on submit only once? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can set a variable on success post and from the next requests make it `return false`

Comment: Do you want to don't enable click on the button more than once?

Comment: Hi @Rohit.007 can you write an answer for it please?

Comment: That is probably because you're adding the same `submit` listener to the `.wc-checkout` element more then once, make sure this code in not inside a loop or another event listener.

Comment: Can you share your HTML part too with minimum working JS?

Comment: I have updated the html

Comment: You can make submit button to disable until ajax successed

Comment: @DavidJawHpan I have solved this problem now. You can view my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding `stopImmediatePropagation();` and `return false;`

Updated code:

```
  j('.wc-checkout').on('submit', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var billing_customer_type = j("#billing_customer_type").val();
    // and so on...

    j.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/mywebsite/?wc-ajax=checkout',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        'billing_customer_type':billing_customer_type,
        // and so on...
      },
      success: function (result) {
        console.log('Order Checked Out');
      },
      error: function(xhr,status,error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      complete:function(){
      }
    });
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); // to prevent more than once submission
    return false; 


  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Check it but you need to test it in your environment.

```js
var isPost = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if (isPost == 0) {
      $.get("https://stackoverflow.com", function() {
        console.log('post');
      });
      isPost = 1;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank for your answer but i have already solved this problem. i have provided my answer in this post